# Why does my property disapear after Object.defineProperty in decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, defineproperty

I have a decorator that casts a string number to a javascript number.

Example: `"87"` -> `87`.

The code is quite simple:

```
function digit(target: any, key: string) {

  // property value
  var _val = this[key];

  // property getter
  var getter = () =>  _val;

  // property setter
  var setter = (newVal) => _val = parseInt(newVal)

  // Create new property with getter and setter
  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get: getter,
    set: setter,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
  });
}

class User {

  @digit
  public id: number;
  public isActive: boolean;

  constructor(instanceData) {
    this.id = instanceData.id;
    this.isActive = instanceData.isActive;
  }
}

let user = new User({
  id: '712',
  isActive: '1'
})

console.log([user.id]) // [ 712 ] as expected
console.log(user) // Person { isActive: '1' }
```

Why doesn't the id field appear in the second console.log and how can I make it appear ?
I can access it but it's hidden in the console.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a [property decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) for an instance property is applied to the *prototype* of the class, not to any *instance*.  That is the best you can do because no instance of `User` exists before you call `new User()`.  When you just use `console.log()` to get debug output you only see the instance's [own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) properties, not the ones on the prototype.

Since all instances share a prototype, you probably don't want to do it this way:

```
let user = new User({
  id: '712',
  isActive: '1'
}) 
let user2 = new User({
  id: '567',
  isActive: '1'
})
console.log(user.id) // 567!
```

One prototype, one `id` value for the whole class.  All `User` objects have the same `id`.  Oops.

---

You probably want to at least do something to instances when they are available:

```
function digit(target: any, key: string) {
  // Create new property with getter and setter
  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get: function () { return this._val },
    set: function (newVal) { this._val = parseInt(newVal) },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
  });
}
```

Notice the use of `this` inside the `get` and `set` methods.  That puts the `_val` property on the instance, so you'll get distinct ones.  You will still not see `id` via `console.log()`, (and you *will* see `_val`).

---

There are too many ways to configure the object so that it prints out what you expect with `console.log()` and behaves the way you expect (one `id` per instance) for me to enumerate here.  As one hint: you could put the property accessor on the instance by modifying the class constructor instead of trying to use a decorator.  And make sure the added `_val` is not enumerable so it does not appear.  Hope that helps; good luck!